# WindowsPhone not refresh/update listbox

Tags: listbox, tableview

i m writing an app where i has created an web service in local network.I m able to grab resources provided by service in android, wp7.1 and ios5.

But i faces a problem, in wp7.1 and ios5 in refreshing the list box and the uitableview controller respectively.

Actually the data source get update in both of this platform but it didn't refresh/update the view which is very important.

if any expertize knows about my problem in depth please help me out from this.if any body has sample code related to updating the view according to the web service kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

i have a solution for this problem in wp7.
may be your web service call fetches the data from catch for the same service call.
try to add current time to show your web service request as new one.
like ".....?&currenttime=...."
try this.

Answer (score 0):

You mention both view and controller so I'm guessing you are using some form of MVVM pattern.

For the controller to update the view a number of things must happen:

1. The controller must be the DataContext for the view. Most MVVM frameworks handle this plumbing for you.
2. The controller property that the listbox in the view is bound against must have NotifyPropertyChanged called or must be an ObservableCollection.